# condition with object arrays in java

Tags: javafx

I am trying to render grid based on object array. but when i launch, it crashes: `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`
If i make the object class static, it does not crash, but the `if` is always true. [Here is my code](https://pastebin.com/vSJyzBkY)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: We require code necessary to understand the question in the question itself. Just posting a link to code is not sufficient.

Comment: i was not able to post code there. so i posted link. if not posting code is better, i could delete that pastebin link if you wan't. or, of you wan't **ONLY** code thats nedded, here it is: https://pastebin.com/YhbLN1hM